# Dependent Sliders with Bokeh, how to write the callbacks

Tags: javascript, python, slider, interactive, bokeh

I want to be able to slide through many plots which are the result of simulations accross 3+ dimensions. I am using the Bokeh package via Python.

For simplicity, let's assume I have two dimensions : *d*, and *nc*. But nc depends on d in the following way:

```
if d=100, nc=56,57
if d=20, nc=5,6
```

And I have 4 pictures:

```
 d_100_nc_56.png, 
 d_100_nc_57.png, 
 d_20_nc_5.png,
 d_20_nc_6.png
```

So I want two sliders, one for *d*, and one for *nc*, to cycle the .png images through the image_url function of Bokeh.plotting.Figure . However, the value of the *nc* slider should update itself as I change the slider in *d*

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_file('image.html')

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(url=['d_100_nc_55.png']))

p = Figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))

callback_nc = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),  code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    old = data['url'][0]
    to_replace=old.substring(old.lastIndexOf("nc_")+3,old.lastIndexOf(".png"))

    data['url'][0] = old.replace(to_replace,f.toString(10))
    source.trigger('change');
""")

callback_d = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    old = data['url'][0]
    to_replace=old.substring(old.lastIndexOf("d_")+2,old.lastIndexOf("_nc_"))

    data['url'][0] = old.replace(to_replace,f.toString(10))
    source.trigger('change');
""")

p.image_url('url',source=source, x=0, y=1,w=1,h=1)
p.text(x=0,y=0,text=source.data['url'])
slider_nc = Slider(start=55, end=65, value=1, step=1, title="nc", callback=callback_nc)
slider_d = Slider(start=20, end=100, value=100, step=80, title="density", callback=callback_d)

layout = vform(slider_nc,slider_d, p)
show(layout)
```

However, I do not know how to pass the *d* slider as an argument to the *nc* slider to fetch its properties and update them on the fly. Is this possible ? Otherwise it limits the use of multiple sliders through bokeh quite substantially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit: updated for more recent versions*

You pass the slider the same way you pass `source`, as an item in the `args` dictionary. Any Python-side Bokeh model you pass there is automatically made available to the callback. Then, BokehJS model properties exactly match the python properties described in the [reference guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html) Here is an example that updates one slider based off another:

```
# Example from Bokeh 0.12.x

from bokeh.plotting import show, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider

s1 = Slider(start=1, end=10, value=1, step=1)
s2 = Slider(start=0, end=1, value=0, step=1)

s1.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=s1, s2=s2), code="""
    s2.end = s1.value;
""")

output_file("foo.html")

show(column(s1,s2))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is amazing !

Comment: What would be the equivalent for the python function as in `CustomJS.from_py_func(callback)`?

Comment: In this case, identical to the updated (simpler) JS code. Personally, I do not like `from_py_func`